# Free UML tool with c++ code generation and doxygen support

Tags: c++, uml, doxygen

I know features such as code generation and doxygen support are usually considered commercial, but I was wondering if there are any free UML tools that support c++ code generation which supports doxygen documentation?

It would be very useful to produce a model with documentation and not have to repeat/edit this to enable the doxygen support.

EDIT: Forgot to mention I am developing under Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) [should be able](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/docs/user-guide%28en%29/ch08.html) to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am developing under linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: @aero117, it seems now (i.e. May 28, 2016) they support ubuntu.

Comment: It is no longer free (2020)

Answer (score 6):

For free and very simple to use there is [dia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dia-installer/) (vectorial diagram editor) with UML + [dia2code](http://dia2code.sourceforge.net/) 
works for "ada|c|cpp|csharp|idl|java|php|php5|python|ruby|shp|sql"

First you draw your UML Class diagram, save it, and than use dia2code on the .dia file.

Since I also tried umbrello (userbase.kde.org/Umbrello) which has more features such as importing code, package/namespace...

Comment: I've tried Umbrello before but it constantly crashes on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

Try [BOUML](http://www.bouml.fr/index.html), it's an excellent multiplatform UML toolbox

Comment: oh yeah actually it's not free since january :/ ; but i's only 30 euros for a year

Comment: it is free again.

Comment: surprising great tool! free!